# Output empty elements

Tags: jaxb

I have a Object with two fields "name" and "address". JAXB ignores the empty elements while transforming the object into XMl.

For ex: if I have name="xyz" and address=null then out will be

```
<name>xyz</name>
```

but what I want as an output as

```
<name>xyz</name>
<address></address>
```

I have seen the option `@XmlElement(nillable="true")` but this gives the output as

```
<name>xyz</name>
<address xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
```

Please help me getting the desired output.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A [JAXB (JSR-222)](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) implementation will output an empty String `""` value as an empty element.  You can set the `address` property to this to get the desired effect.

---

**UPDATE #1**

> I have updated my question. Basically the address element is NULL. Is
>   this solution applicable to that as well?

You could leverage [Marshal Event Callbacks](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/Marshaller.html#marshalEventCallback) to adjust the value of `address`.

```java
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Customer {

    private String name;
    private String address;

    private void beforeMarshal(Marshaller marshaller) {
        if(null == address) {
            address = "";
        }
    }

    private void afterMarshal(Marshaller marshaller) {
        if("".equals(address)) {
            address = null;
        }
    }

}
```

---

**UPDATE #2**

> The only concern is that if I have 10 fields in the class I will have
>   to write if for all the fields. Is there any other solution?

If you use [**EclipseLink MOXy**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) as your JAXB provider (I'm the MOXy lead), then you could use an `XmlAdapter` for this use case.

**XmlAdapter (StringAdapter)**

```java
package forum14691333;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;

public class StringAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, String> {

    @Override
    public String marshal(String string) throws Exception {
        if(null == string) {
            return "";
        }
        return string;
    }

    @Override
    public String unmarshal(String string) throws Exception {
        if("".equals(string)) {
            return null;
        }
        return string;
    }

}
```

**package-info**

Then if you specify it at the package level it will apply to all mapped fields/properties of type `String` within that package.

```java
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(value=StringAdapter.class, type=String.class)
package forum14691333;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.*;
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/02/jaxb-and-package-level-xmladapters.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/specifying-eclipselink-moxy-as-your.html

Comment: Hi Blaise, Thanks for quick response. I have updated my question. Basically the address element is NULL. Is this solution applicable to that as well?

Comment: Thanks Blaise..This solution works. The only concern is that if I have 10 fields in the class I will have to write if for all the fields. Is there any other solution?

Comment: I am new to package-info.java. I did the same way as explained but the  output is not coming in desired way. I am working on eclipse Helios. I put a debug point in eclipse and started in debug mode but the pointer never stopped at this point. can u please help me on this?

Comment: @Ritesh - The `XmlAdapter` approach will only work when using MOXy as your JAXB provider.  See:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/specifying-eclipselink-moxy-as-your.html

Answer (score 1):

If you use EclipseLink MOXy as your JAXB provider then you could use

```
@XmlNullPolicy(emptyNodeRepresentsNull = true, nullRepresentationForXml = XmlMarshalNullRepresentation.EMPTY_NODE)
@XmlElement(name = "address", nillable = true)
private String address;
```

By using this way, you don't have to write adapter for all the fields

Answer (score 0):

Simply set an empty string default value on the field.

```
@XmlElement(required="true")
private String address = "";
```

and you will get

```
<address></address>
```